# transaction context and future annotation

Tags: apex

I need to call a method from an existing method. I need to do some DML and service invokation in caller method. I am doing DML in called method. Can i separate the two transactions by annotating the called method with @future. Caller method is annotated with @RemoteAction. I want any error or slow processing in called method to not have an impact on called method.

Comment: @future will be a separate transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @future annotation with the called method solved the problem. I did not get uncommitted data warning anymore while making other callouts.